# Angular Library Debugging - WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ng-packagr, angular-cli-v9

We have created our own angular library and published those artifacts in AWS CodeArtifact.
Those 2 artifacts we are importing into another project.I would like to debug those 2 libraries and want to add breakpoint, what's the best solution for this. Here is what we are using.

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.8
Node: 10.16.0
IDE :- Webstrom
```

Comment: anyone can help us for this issue ?